# Creating object of array dynamically in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a variable which would look like this:

```
var projects = [
  {
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library"        
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery"
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine"
  }
];
```

How can I create such variable dynamically?  I would be writing this in one loop where I want to keep on adding values to the declared variable.

Comment: Um, what would be the source of your data?

Comment: `var arr = []; /* loop over data */arr.push({value: ...., }); /* end loop */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var data = [];
var objPush = {};
objPush.value = "jquery";
objPush.label = "jQuery";
objPush.desc = "the write less, do more, JavaScript library";

data.push(objPush);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
var projects = [];
projects.push({
    value : "<some-value>",
    label : "<some label>",
    desc : "<description>"
});
projects.push({
    value : "<some-value>",
    label : "<some label>",
    desc : "<description>"
});
....
```